# How to get rid of business template card borders

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Created business card from template. But now blue borders appear on the page too. How do I remove them from psd?[image]

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: Photoshop is the wrong tool for making business cards.

Answer (score 2):

Open your Layers palette. Poke around. Delete as needed.

Comment: It's not the layer but something like measurement tool. http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/real-estate-business-card.zip here is the file. please open

Comment: @Tural The purpose of this site is for [Q&A about Graphic Design issues](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), not as a facility for others to fix your file for you.